# How to obtain $\triangle^5 f(x)$ easily...

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

The value of $\triangle^5[(1-x)(1-x^2)(1+x^2)]$ is

(a) 5!

(b) 0

(c) 1

(d) 5

I am not getting how to deal with this sum..
What I know is $\triangle f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, and if I use this to obtain $\triangle^5[(1-x)(1-x^2)(1+x^2)]$, then it will be very complicated to solve..

So instead of directly solving this I tried to obtained $\triangle^5 f(x)$ as formula

So I got

$$\triangle^2 f(x)=f(x+2)-2f(x+1)+f(x)$$

$$\triangle^3 f(x)=f(x+3)-3f(x+2)+3f(x+1)-f(x)$$

$$\triangle^4 f(x)=f(x+4)-4f(x+3)+6f(x+2)-4f(x+1)+f(x) $$

$$\triangle^5 f(x)=f(x+5)-5f(x+4)+10f(x+3)-10f(x+2)+4f(x+1)-f(x)$$, clearly its forms binomial expansion type formula..

But still if I susbtitute the values of $f(x+5),f(x+4),f(x+3),f(x+2),f(x+1)$ and $f(x)$, it will be complicate to solve as much multiplications will be involved...

Is there a better and less time taking way, such questions are generally part of  a competitive exam... where maximum 2-3 minutes can be given to such questions...

thanks in advance!!

Comment: $\Delta^n(x^n)=n!$ and $\Delta^n(x^m)=0$ for $m<n$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function simplifies to $(1-x)(1-x^4) = 1 - x -x^4 + x^5$.

Recall that $\Delta x^n = (x+1)^n - x^n$.

So just iterate on that $5$ times. But we see that $\Delta^n x^m = 0$ if $m <n$ (e.g. $\Delta^3 x^2 = 0$). This is because $\Delta x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Hence $n$ differences turns it constant, and $n+1$ will make it zero.

So we can already see
$$
\Delta^5 \Big( 1 - x -x^4 + x^5 \Big) = \Delta^5 x^5
$$
with no real computation. What remains is trivial, even if we work from the definition and forego formulas like $\Delta^n x^n = n!$.